# Implementing JSON REST Service to elasticsearch using Spring/Camel

Tags: json, spring, rest, elasticsearch, apache-camel

I am a complete Camel FNG migrating from a JMS service to a RESTful service; part of that is integrating with an elasticsearch server. I am using Fuse with the Spring DSL.

The main idea is to poll for  data from a whole bunch of servers running a REST service, marshal them to XML (if necessary, see below), strip the top level key (`foo:{...}`)  and push each of the keys to an elasticsearch database. a reply from the service would be of the form:

```
{"foo": {"bar":{"type":"tweet","info":"blahblah"},"baz":{"type":"tweet","info":"blahblah"}}}
```

My questions are as follows:

1-How do I get data from the webservice? I dug around looking for a concise example, to no avail. If I understand correctly, it involves the jetty component in camel. say I want to pull json from http://myrestservice:7700.

2- Does the json need to be marshaled to XML to remove the top-level key?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use camel-cxf [2] producer to call those running REST services and pass the result which will be your json to a processor and then use JSonPath [2] to traverse over your json and customize it the way you want it.

[1] http://camel.apache.org/cxfrs.html (see "Consuming a REST Request - Default Binding Style" section) 
[2] http://camel.apache.org/jsonpath.html